# PHP Mysql table conversion to excel:The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the extension

Tags: php

I have a code that converts mysql table to excel sheet. It converts and the excel sheet is downloaded but whenever I try to open the file it gives an error msg in excel 2007:"The file you are trying to open is in a different format than specified by the extension...".The excel sheet opens after I click on 'Yes' but it is nothing but a white blank sheet.I have seen the similar posts but none of them solves my problem...Please help...Thank you

```
    <?php
      include('dbcon.php');
    ?>

    <?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM stu_gen_info";
$rec = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($rec);

for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name($rec,$i)."\\t";
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($rec))
{
    $line = '';
    foreach($row as $value)
    {                                            
        if((!isset($value)) || ($value == ""))
        {
            $value = "\\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\\n";
}

$data = str_replace("\\r" , "" , $data);

if ($data == "")
{
    $data = "\\n No Record Found!\n";                        
}

header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reports.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
print "$header\\n$data";

    ?>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that outputs an xls file. YOu are sending a tab-delimited file (and not a properly formatted one). You *can* open a tab-delimited file in Excel, but it will complain if you name the file "xls". I'm just curios why you use \\t and \\n instead of \t and \n.

Comment: You either output an XLS file or a TSV; currently you're doing both and neither.

Comment: ummm...so can I get a working code or something?It will be really helpful for me and I am in a hurry too as I have to submit my final year project the day after tomorrow...so plz help..ty

Comment: formatted the \\t and \\n to \t and \n...but the same problem...

Comment: Read kainaw's first comment and fix your code. Open your generated file in a text editor (I recommand [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)) to see if the out put of your script really is what you expected.

Comment: I opened the generated file in notepad...I got the column headers and the data and it was in a html document

Comment: how can I format the table to a proper xls file??? I searched the net but I got this and all were somewhat similar to this..I applief the other codes too but the problem was same..

Comment: the error message is still showing but I am getting the data...no more blank file....Thank you everyone for your kind help but I am getting a  partcular data of a column in a different format i.e. in the mysql table the data is 09106001002 but in excel it is showing as 9.11E+09...Any help??

Answer (score -2):

try adding this

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
```

Comment: added it but the problem persists... :(

Comment: try removing this line : `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");`